# Why does my Page lose focus?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, focus

I have Page, and it loses focus when I tap on an empty part of it. I tried putting a Border as the background, but that loses focus too when I tap it. Why does this happen?

What I really need to do is disable a WebView when the user opens the AppBar or the Settings Charm

Some example code to demonstrate the problem (watch the output window):

XAML:

```
<Page
    x:Name="Pagey"
    x:Class="FocusTest.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:FocusTest"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" GotFocus="Focus" LostFocus="LoseFocus">

    <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" GotFocus="Focus" LostFocus="LoseFocus">
        <StackPanel>
            <Button x:Name="Clicky" Content="Clicky" GotFocus="Focus" LostFocus="LoseFocus" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></Button>
            <Border x:Name="Border" Width="100" Height="100" Background="Red" GotFocus="Focus" LostFocus="LoseFocus"></Border>
            <Button x:Name="Clicky2" Content="Clicky2" GotFocus="Focus" LostFocus="LoseFocus" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Code behind:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace FocusTest
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        void Focus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Focus({0})", (sender as FrameworkElement).Name);
        }

        void LoseFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("LoseFocus({0})", (sender as FrameworkElement).Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: remove in grid focus events. same this: <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

Comment: Doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Look like your `Border` is inside the `RootGrid` So that every time when you tap `Border's tap event` will occur and `LostFocus` Event fired.
 Better you can set `LostFocus` event on the same `RootGrid`. Then it may work fine.
 Please try it.
Thanks.